# R Shiny - Subset dataframe based on reactive input

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app and I need to subset a dataframe based on a user input. I have tried many different ways to do this but I keep running into errors. Currently, this seems to be the simplest method but I get the following error:

**Warning in is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
Error in `==.default`(test$MARKET, var) : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types**

I am pretty stuck. Does anyone have some guidance for me? Thanks!

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      var <- reactive({input$var})

      subsetTest <- subset(test, test$MARKET==var)

      y <- subsetTest()$PRICE
      x <- subsetTest()$DATE

  output$ngplot <- renderPlot({
    print(ggplot(data=subsetTest(), aes(x=y, y=x)) + geom_line())
  })
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, in the `subset` call you can skip out `test$` (not the cause of your problem):

```
subset(test, MARKET==var)
```

I suspect your problem is that `var` is not a string, it is the output of `reactive`. Try getting the value with `var()` instead of `var`

```
subset(test, MARKET==var())
```