# Error message for counting the number of peaks within a time range

Tags: r, count, sum

I am counting the number of peaks between two time points using the following code:

```
sum(peaks>=1 & peaks<=25)
```

However, I keep getting the following message:

```
Error in peaks >= 1 : 
  comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Both x and y variables are numbers, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error message. This is an excerpt of some example data:

```
0   0    
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   14.6464
6   14.6464
7   14.6464
8   14.6464
9   16.7139
10  20.8488
11  20.8488
12  19.0305
13  15.3939
14  15.3939
15  15.3939
16  15.0954
17  14.4985
18  14.4985
19  14.4985
20  15.2851
21  16.8582
22  16.8582
23  16.796
24  16.6715
25  16.6715
```

I have researched this but the reasons for other error messages haven't applied to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377291/r-shiny-subset-dataframe-based-on-reactive-input) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268546/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-documents-where-a-field-is-within-a-certain-range).

Comment: You need to say on what you are subsetting, then apply the `sum` to this subset. The general form is `sum(vector_of_something[vector_of_something_else>=1 & vector_of_something_else<=25)`. In case of a data.frame `df`, `sum(df$vector_of_something[df$vector_of_something_else>=1 & df$vector_of_something_else<=25)` or `with(df, sum(vector_of_something[vector_of_something_else>=1 & vector_of_something_else<=25))`.

Comment: @Pascal Thank you for your reply. How do the subsets differ? sum(df$peak[df$peak>=1 & df$peak<=25])

Comment: Could you offer some more information? Like of the x and y you mention, which of them is peaks? Or is peaks a dataframe and you want to find all values of the data frame which are between the two values specified?

Comment: @SamPassmore The peaks are a function I created called peaks based off of y. x is seconds. The x and y are the original data.

Comment: If peaks is a function then that is your problem. You cannot use a function that way. I have replicated your problem with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a function in this way.
These comparisons are used for subsetting data and cannot be applied to functions

What you are doing is equivalent to

```
read.csv == 1
```

This will give the same error and obviously doesn't make any sense

To acheive your goal of finding peaks of the data. You should try something like the following

This creates some data similar to your example - assuming you have a dataframe

```
x = c(0:25)
y = runif(26, 0, 30)
data = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

Here we can see what indices for x are greater than 10, and what indices are greater that 15 for y. True meaning they fit the criteria, false meaning they didn't. In R we can use T/F as a tool to subset data.

```
data$x >= 10
data$y <= 15
```

Here we can see which fit both of this criteria. Again True and False.

```
data$x >= 10 & data$y <= 15
```

And this shows us the number of rows that fit that criteria - which seems to be what you want. But doesn't identify which rows they are - like the previous line.

```
sum(data$x >= 10 & data$y <= 15)
```

If we actually what to see which rows fit this criteria I would recommend using subset in this way

```
subset(data, x >= 10 & y <= 15)
```

This will result in all the rows that fit the criteria from your dataframe.

Comment: I have peaks of data and I am trying to count the number of peaks between a time range.